# Can I upgrade a FC4 server to the latest version over the network?

Tags: fedora, yum

I found an old server with `2.6.17-1.2142_FC4smp` installed. Is it possible to upgrade this to the latest fedora-version? It seems that the required packages does not exist on http://download.fedora.redhat.com/ when I try to use yum.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like it's possible, in theory, according to this:
http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/YumUpgradeFaq

But really... Make a full backup and install the latest CentOS release instead (assuming you're a red hat shop).
That will be quicker, more likely to work, and it's a more appropriate server distro.

Answer (score 0):

Support for FC4 ended four years ago, you won't be able to get any new packages from Fedora.